# Visit data issues using Google Analytics with Adobe Air for iOS

Tags: ios, air, google-analytics, adobe

We are using GA for Flash in our iOS app ported over with Adobe Air and are seeing some funky numbers being collected in Google Analytics. We ran some tests and saw that every time the app was opened it would count both a new visit and a new unique visit, even if it was just a minimize and re-open.

We would assume that the 30 minute time out would be in effect here and that even on a quick minimize and re-open that GA would count that as one visit. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Does anyone know how we could set-up the GA implementation to record unique visits based off of a user ID given on first launch of the app, and/or have it accurately count visits?

Has anyone seen something similar to this before?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics allows you to set up [Custom Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#SettingUpEventTracking) to track user interactions so this could be dispatched depending on a flag stored in a config file (to determine if it is the first time the application is run).

Depending on your implementation of Air, i.e AS3 / Javascript, if you are using AS3 you may have to utilise the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) api to call a javscript method from the application.

This would then allow you to track these custom events and ignore the erroneous default visits?